# Zip command creating a directory while unzipping the file

Tags: shell, zip

Am creating a zip file in the script, when I run the script and go to the target folder and unzip the zip file I created in script, it's creating a directory and unzipping the file in that directory.

Below is the code in the script.

```
for fname in `cat $Filenm`
 do
  echo $fname
  fnme=$(echo ${fname}|awk -F\/ '{print $8}')
  echo $fnme>>$scriptLog
  tofilename="${date_new}_${fnme}"
   zip -r $tofilename.zip $fileDir/$fnme
  rm $fileDir/$fnme
  mv $tofilename.zip $todir
```

When I go to `$todir` after the script execution and unzip `$tofilename.zip`, it's creating the `$fileDir` in the `$todir` and unzipping the file there, so in `$todir` I have to go into like 5 sub directories to see my text file.

I want the text file in the zip file to be unzipped into the `$todir`, but not the way its happening.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-j` option to `zip` (`-j` for "junk paths") which will discard the name of the directory and keep only the file name.

Also, you don't need the `-r` option (`-r` for "recurse into directories") since you're passing it a single file name (the `-r` option is useful when you want to store a whole directory tree into the zipfile.)

So this line should be enough to store the file in the zipfile without the directory name:

```
zip -j $tofilename.zip $fileDir/$fnme
```

Another option is to keep storing the full directory path in the zipfile and simply discarding it when you unpack it, by passing the `unzip` command the `-j` option, which works similarly to how this option works when zipping.

Comment: Thanks a lot Filipe Brandenburger , i changed it to zip -j $tofilename.zip $fileDir/$fnme , it worked.